# Using Wordpress and zend framework to serve the same website

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, zend-framework, url-routing

My web site is running two server side applications: application for logged-in users running on PHP (using Zend framework) and Wordpress application for the public, non-loggedin users.
I am using Apache.

I would like that requests from logged-in users Would be served by the index.php file of Zendframework and those from non-logged in users by Wordpress index.php file.

Note, I prefer not to have different URLs for the two frameworks. For example: mydomain.com should lead to both sites according to the log-in status.

One way I thought doing this, is by always starting at Zend, check if the user is not logged-in, and if so perform _forward or similar action to Wordpress.

Is that possible? Should I do something else?
Thanks.

Comment: How does your zend urls look like? Is zend in subfolder?

Comment: they look like: domainname.com/controller_name/action_name

Comment: so how do you know when user is using wordpress part of the site and when zf?

Comment: @insanebits when a user is logged-in, she has a session (through cookie) established. So on ZF I can check if the user is loggeed-in or not. What I am not sure about is when the user is not logged-in how to goto the wordpress application.

Comment: can you add file structure and htaccess file of the root folder, then maybe I would be able to help.

Comment: @insanebits The file structure is: site_name/http/index.php;     site_name/wordpress/index.php;    htaccess file: RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|swf|woff|ttf)$ index.php
RewriteBase /http
order allow,deny
allow from all